# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method sendMessage(View)

Tags: android, methods, illegalstateexception

java code:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity<View> extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

the error message:

```
06-18 15:19:12.493: E/AndroidRuntime(799): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method sendMessage(View) in the activity class com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button
```

I  really do not know the reason about that，and i check the case about the method name,that's ok.
Who can help me?

Comment: your class declaration must public class MainActivity extends Activity{} instead public class MainActivity<View> extends Activity{}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `<View>`. Also move your initialization of Editext to oncreate(). Need not initialize editext evey time on button click.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
private EdiText editext; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message); 
} 
....
```

Comment: remove <view>,Please explain the situation in detail。

Comment: MainActivity is your class name. Your class extends Activity. You the set the content of your layout to activity. why do you need this MainActivity<view>. its not of the type view

Answer (score 1):

you have to declare your activity as :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
}
```

and also you need to declare your button in your `onCreate()` method like below:

```
Button button_send= (Button)findViewById(R.id.your_Button_Id);
```

**update:**

Also you have to assign an id for your button in your manifest and refer to it above.